# Gtalk implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, gmail, chat, xmppframework

Is there any way to implement Gtalk in iOS application,i just want to create an application, in which user can simply login with his/her gmail account and, chat with those people who are in his chat list.

if any one know how to do this, then please help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Talk uses **[XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)** (Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol). You can use for example the [**XMPPFramework**](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) framework to implement it. This framework is listed on a XMPP Foundation [website](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

> **XMPPFramework** provides a core implementation of RFC-3920 (the xmpp
>   standard), along with the tools needed to read & write XML.

Check out the [Getting Started Guide for iOS](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS). It contains an example iOS project.

Furthermore, have a look into [Google Talk Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/talk/talk_developers_home?csw=1). There is a section called: *I want to build a client that connects to the Google Talk service* which describes steps you should take to implement a client.

Comment: i tried the link you provide, but i am not understanding how to implement XMPPFramework in my ios application, i am using [this code](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration--mobile-7190) but it also not working with my gmail account. Please help me , and thanks.