# iOS:XMPPFramework: Cant able to login using gmail account

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am developing one simple chat application using XMPPFramework from [robbiehanson](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework). I have installed **eJabberd** server in my system and created some users. I set **hostname = "localhost"** and tried to login with that user credentials. It is successfully logged in. When I change the hostname ie **hostname="talk.google.com"**. I cant able to login. I got **"Sign-in attempt prevented"** mail and

`<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized></not-authorized></failure>`

FYI,

```
- (BOOL)connectWithUsername:(NSString*)username WithPassword:(NSString*)pwd
{
    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }

   // NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyJID];
    //NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword];
    NSString* myJID=username;
    NSString* myPassword=pwd;
    //
    // If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID,
    // uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
    //
    // Replace me with the proper JID and password:
    //  myJID = @"user@gmail.com/xmppframework";
    //  myPassword = @"";

    if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
        NSLog(@"JID and password must be set before connecting!");

        return NO;
    }

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:100 error:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                             message:@"See console for error details."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

        return NO;
    }


    [self goOnline];

    return YES;
}
```

Am I need to register app in Google Developer Console? 
Kindly provide me the solution to integrate Gmail account in the XMPPFramework.

Comment: [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865340/gtalk-implementation-in-ios)

Comment: @the_UB I couldnt see

Comment: click on text `check it`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have set your JID and hostname correctly ?

There are some instructions in `XMPPStream.h` file just above `hostname` property.

You should also know that configurations for Google servers on XMPP differs a bit, Make sure required configurations are done inside `XMPPXOAuth2Google.m` file and also inside `goOnline` method on delegate.

Some default changes are done by `XMPPFramework` :

```
- (void)goOnline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit

    NSString *domain = [xmppStream.myJID domain];

    //Google set their presence priority to 24, so we do the same to be compatible.

    if([domain isEqualToString:@"gmail.com"] ||
       [domain isEqualToString:@"gtalk.com"] ||
       [domain isEqualToString:@"talk.google.com"])
    {
        NSXMLElement *priority = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"priority" stringValue:@"24"];
        [presence addChild:priority];
    }

    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}
```

Comment: @Thanks UnknOwn.Bit , What kind of changes need to be done in XMPPXOAuth2Google.m?

Comment: Did you get any answer ?